# How to make this Scheme function not tail recursive?

Tags: recursion, scheme, tail-recursion, fold, foldleft

I can't figure out how can I make this tail recursive Scheme function not tail recursive anymore. Anyone can help me?

```
(define (foldrecl f x u)
  (if (null? x)
      u 
      (foldrecl f (cdr x) (f (car x) u))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**left** folds are inheritly iterative, but you can easily make them recursive by adding a continuation. eg.

```
(let ((value expresion-that-calculates))
  value)
```

So in your case:

```
(define (foldrecl f x u)
  (if (null? x)
      u 
      (let ((result (foldrecl f (cdr x) (f (car x) u))))
        result)))
```

While this looks promising it does not guarantee that a smart Scheme implementation figures out that `result` is just returned and make it a tail call instead. Right folds are easier since they are inherently recursive:

```
(define (fold-right proc tail lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      tail
      (proc (car lst)
            (fold-right proc tail (cdr lst)))))
```

Here you clearly see the recursive part needs to become a argument to `cons` and thus never in tail position unless it is the base case.

Also notice it's slightly simpler to see what arguments goes where when the procedure is called `proc`, the tail of the result `tail` and the list argument `lst`. You don't even need to read my code to know how to use it, but yours I have no idea what `x` and `u` and ti doesn't help that the argument order doesn't follow any `fold` implementations known in Scheme.

Comment: Thank you so much! Yeah good point about the names of the arguments. I just wanted to look simpler but it really doesn't do that.

Answer (score 1):

The recursive call is in tail position, so put it inside another procedure call like this:

```
(define (identity x) x)

(define (foldrecl f x u)
  (if (null? x)
      u 
      (identity (foldrecl f (cdr x) (f (car x) u)))))
```

now the recursive call is not in tail position, it is not tail recursive anymore.

A compiler is allowed to optimize away the identity function if it knows that it does nothing but hopefully it wont.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing, compose a *plan* for doing it; only in the end, *do*:

```
(define (foldreclr f xs a)
  (define (go xs)
     (if (null? xs) 
        (lambda (a) a)
        (let ((r (go (cdr xs))))    ; first, recursive call;
           (lambda                  ; afterwards, return a plan:
                  (a)               ;    given an a, to
             (r                     ;    perform the plan for (cdr xs)
               (f (car xs) a))))))  ;    AFTER processing (car x) and a.
  ((go xs)                          ; when the overall plan is ready,
           a))                      ;    use it with the supplied value
```

The internal function `go` follows the *right fold* pattern. It makes the recursive call first, and only afterwards it composes and returns a value, the plan to *first* combine the list's head element with the *accumulator* value, and *then* perform the plan for the list's tail -- just like the original `foldrecl` would do.

When the whole list is turned into a plan of action, that action is finally performed to transform the supplied initial accumulator value -- performing the same calculation as the original `foldrecl` left fold.

This is known as *leaning so far right you come back left again.*(*)

```
> (foldreclr - (list 1 2 3 4) 0)   ; 4-(3-(2-(1-0)))
2
> (foldreclr - (list 4 3 2 1) 0)   ; 1-(2-(3-(4-0)))
-2
```

See also:

- [Foldl as foldr](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldl_as_foldr_alternative)
- (*) [Evolution of a Haskell programmer](https://willamette.edu/~fruehr/haskell/evolution.html) (fun read)

<sub>(sorry, these are in Haskell, but Haskell is a Lisp too.)</sub>